# change location of every object selected

Tags: objects, select

How to change the location from every object selected?
Looks like in the older versions of blender you alt click the location, and then it changes it for every object (I'm not sure of that), but how do you do it in blender 2.8?
[image]

Comment: do you want all your object to go the exact same location?

Comment: @moonboots Yes I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all your objects, at last select the one you want to copy the location from, then right click on the *Location* panel and choose *Copy All to Selected*.

In order to copy only one value, put your mouse cursor over the value and choose *Copy Single to Selected*.

Comment: Is there a way to change only the y location?

Comment: put your mouse cursor over the value and choose Copy Single to Selected

Comment: Oh ok, thanks...